# Angular 2 long app loading

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have problem with long loading angular 2 app, it takes almost 8 seconds. I noticed that the most time takes loading rxjs.  There are tens of requests to rxjs/observable rxjs/add rxjs/operator

What can i do to improve my app loading?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong link. Should be https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8542

Comment: Angular CLI now supports bundling for production, reducing app sizes and the number of requests made by huge factors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543232/angular-2-reduce-app-size-in-addition-to-bundling-minification

Answer (score 1):

If you are using systemjs as module loader.

1. Including bundled versions, angular related modules comes with umd bundles.
   Part of `systemjs.config.js`:

   ```
   var umdPackages = [
    "@angular/common",
    "@angular/compiler",
    "@angular/core",
    "@angular/http",
    "@angular/platform-browser",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
    "@angular/router",
    "@angular/testing"
   ];
   umdPackages.forEach(function(name) {
     var main = name.slice(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + ".umd.js";
     packages[name] = { main: main, format: "amd", defaultExtension: "js"};
   });
   ```

   It will reduce requests by ~300.
2. In theory, same possible for rxjs. There are bundles `umd` and `system.register`. But it doesn't work, loading still happens one by one file (for rxjs) - `isFunction.js`, `Observer.js`, etc.